# Use Vue dev tool with Laravel Valet

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-valet, vue-devtools

I have a laravel project running on laravel valet and I can't get the vue dev tool to work on it.

Here is what it says:

> Vue.js is detected on this page. Devtools inspection is not available because it's in production mode or explicitly disabled by the author.

I have gone to manage extensions and selected allow access to file URLs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you using any build tools such as webpack?

Comment: Look in your app.js file and check to see if the line `Vue.config.devtools = true;` is there.  Also check in your .env file if the mode is set as  `APP_ENV=development`

Comment: @btl I am using laravel mix. I am very new to laravel mix so I’m not positive I set it all up properly.

Comment: @skribe so my `APP_ENV=local` and I don't have the line `Vue.config.devtools = true;` I will do add that line. As for .env, do i need to switch that?

Comment: `local` should be fine.

Comment: ok is there somewhere specific i need to add that other line of code because it isn't working

Comment: It is best to include that line first thing after you require vue itself.

Comment: ok that is where i put it. it still doesn't want to work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164630/discussion-between-skribe-and-l-fox).

Comment: I added a comment in in the chat.

Comment: Ok I appreciate it though I will not be able to chat right now. Thank you.